# Is the Arcturan kdopht kosher?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Arcturan *kdopht* has nine legs, in three rows. The three left and three right hooves are cloven (in thirds), but the midline hooves are more like the surface of a rough file, with innumerable small points protruding from a solid block of hoof. Its diet is purely vegetarian, insofar as the term can be applied to Arcturan biota. After eating, it regurgitates straight upward and catches (most of) the semi-digested mass in its mouth, then chews it over again before swallowing (via a separate throat) to complete the process of digestion. Is the *kdopht* kosher, assuming of course proper shechita and kashering?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Is this creature something of your own imagination, or from existing scifi/fantasy literature?

Comment: Two throats?  Doesn't this create a difficulty, since one throat might be properly being shechted while, the other one is screaming bloody murder...>

Comment: @Scimonster: My own imagination.

Comment: @Gary: Good question. Let's assume that they're both properly shechted. Or even better: they start out at the back of the mouth as one, and divide further down, and shechita can easily be done above the split.

Comment: @Mark A. Mandel - How intelligent is this thing, anyhow?  Does he recite poetry with one throat while humming an accompanying tune with the other? ....just saw the Twilight Zone's "To Serve Man" episode the other day....maybe there's better food choices?

Comment: @Gary: No more intelligent than a goat. And the second throat doesn't produce sound.

Comment: @Mark A. Mandel -okay, just making sure.  In that case, shecht away if you can and I'll try a plate of kdopht tikka masala...or a skewer of shish-kdopht-bob.. or a U-bone kdopht steak.. ,,or kdopht and eggs....or whatever the usual way it's prepared.

Comment: @Gary OK SamIAm

Comment: Here we go again - dinnertime! kdopht Rangoon appetizers, then kdophta ball soup, kdopht brisket (on rye if you want a nice sandwich), with kdopht giblet gravy, and since it's Purim, kdophtaschens...

Comment: How do you pronounce the thing's name exactly? :/

Comment: Just the way it's spelled. In the IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet, not India Pale Ale), ['k̚doːpt]. But you can say "kaDOFT" if you want to. The whole world knows that our crazy spelling* twists our reading pronunciations out of all recognizability.    *though, through, plough, cough, thorough, thought ... Had enough?

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the hooves seem to mean that it is not kosher. You state that the outer hooves are split in three rather than two. Similarly, the midline hooves are not split at all. Note that the word used for the splitting is "parsa". That is, split like the Persians. Just as the Persians are split in two (the Persians and the Medes), so too an animal with split hooves is split in two.

The description of the midline hooves are similar to that of a camel which is an undifferentiated pad.

The regurgitation appears to be similar to that of a rabbit which regugitates and eats.

"There is nothing new under the sun". We already refer to this type of animal as like a shafan or arneves.

Comment: But the camel does not have cloven hooves at all, which the _kdopht_ does— just not ALL of them. And does the tanakhic requirement specify that they must be cloven in twain, no more?

Comment: @MarkA.Mandel Yes but the wording is not that it has some split hooves, but that it is "a split hooved" animal. Any non-split hoof would invalidate it. Besides which the implication of the word used is split in half.

Comment: @MarkA.Mandel I added a Purim Torah "reason" why it must be split in two and no more.